# Did Major Gilbert survive?

Tags: violet-evergarden

In the last episode of *Violet Evergarden*, when introducing herself, Violet paused and had a bit surprised look.

Is it possible that Gilbert is the one she met there in that cottage? Has there been any statement from the author on this?

Comment: I'd imagine she would've had a much bigger reaction if it was him.

Comment: Note that [there will be a second season with an original story](https://honeysanime.com/violet-evergarden-season-2/). A new information might come after the 2nd season comes.

Comment: I do think that Major Gilbert did survive the explosion due to the fact that they never found the body, and the reaction of violet on the very last episode. Though I do agree with some that say, her reaction would have been more dramatic if it really was him at the door, but I also believe that since she had just recently experienced emotions, she had not experienced true joy yet, so her reaction would be most definitely dulled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Light Novel the anime is based on,

> he did survive. He woke up before Violet and told everyone to keep it a secret from Violet so she could grow as a person beyond being a emotionally-stunted loli super soldier while he advanced upwards in the army as part of a spec ops team. He made his grand reappearance on the train to save the day.

On the other hand, the anime

> left it vague because it's kinda a crap plot motivation. I personally hate motivations that boil down to "I'm doing this assholish thing so you don't have to suffer/worry, never mind that me being an asshole makes you suffer even more".
>
>  The anime staff likely thought that letting him come back would weaken Violet's character arc.

Comment: Probably I'd like to bring attention that [there will be season 2 with presumably an original story](https://honeysanime.com/violet-evergarden-season-2/). That's one reason I was unsure to answer it now (in addition to only found the answer from googling without watching/reading it)

Comment: @AkiTanaka that's why I explicitly mentioned that it's from the light novel. To give the "statement from the author on this". It keeps this answer relevant even when the anime continues and goes the other way.